# Display only child terms of a specific parent term of a custom taxonomy, for each custom post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type named 'hub', with a custom taxonomy named '5imp'.
The '5imp' taxonomy has 5 parent terms, and I would like to display a list of all the post-assigned child terms for only one of those parent terms, named 'top', below each custom post.